# Sql query grouped by contigious foreign key values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this:

```
+----+-------------------------+----------+----------+
| ID |      DateReceived       | Quantity | VendorID |
+----+-------------------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2010-08-09 06:53:44.783 |        2 |        1 |
|  2 | 2010-08-01 13:31:26.893 |        1 |        1 |
|  3 | 2010-07-26 07:52:29.403 |        2 |        1 |
|  4 | 2011-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
|  5 | 2011-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
|  6 | 2011-03-22 11:27:01.000 |        1 |        2 |
|  7 | 2011-03-18 09:04:58.000 |        1 |        1 |
|  8 | 2011-12-17 08:21:29.000 |        1 |        3 |
|  9 | 2012-08-10 10:55:20.000 |        9 |        3 |
| 10 | 2012-08-02 20:18:10.000 |        5 |        1 |
| 11 | 2012-07-12 20:44:36.000 |        3 |        1 |
| 12 | 2012-07-05 20:45:29.000 |        1 |        1 |
| 13 | 2013-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
| 14 | 2013-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
+----+-------------------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to sort the data by the `DateReceived` and sum the `Quantity`. BUT, I want to sum the `Quantity` grouped by the `VendorID` as long as they are adjacent like the example output below.

```
+----------+----------+
| VendorID | Quantity |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        5 |
|        2 |        3 |
|        1 |        1 |
|        3 |       10 |
|        1 |        9 |
|        2 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```

I currently am doing this by loading all rows and going through them in my application code. This is currently a bottleneck in my software that I would like to elimiate.

What is a MS Sql Server query to generate the desired output?

PS. Any suggestions for a better title?

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by adjacent? As in the `VendorID` is +/-1 from another?

Comment: @w0lf I'm using SQL server 2005

Comment: @Romoku Actually the `VendorID` in the real data is a GUID. By adjacent I mean next to each other when sorted by the `DateReceived`.

Comment: I also asked the same question for MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895420/107768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT  z.VendorID, z.GroupID,
        MIN(z.DateReceived) AS DateReceivedStart, 
        MAX(z.DateReceived) AS DateReceivedStop, 
        SUM(z.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM
(
    SELECT  y.VendorID,
            y.RowNum1 - y.RowNum2 AS GroupID,
            y.DateReceived,
            y.Quantity
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.DateReceived) AS RowNum1,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.VendorID, x.DateReceived) AS RowNum2
        FROM    @MyTable x
    ) y
) z
GROUP BY z.VendorID, z.GroupID
ORDER BY DateReceivedStart
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23439)

Comment: SQL Server 2005 and above

Answer (score 4):

In **SQL Server 2005+** you can do this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        VendorID, Quantity,
        row_number() over(partition by VendorID order by DateReceived) as rn1,
        row_number() over(order by DateReceived) as rn2
    from Table1
)
select
    VendorID, sum(Quantity) as Quantity
from cte 
group by VendorID, rn2 - rn1
order by min(rn2)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5032a/11)</kbd>**

In **SQL Server 2012** you can use lag() function:

```
with cte as (
    select
        VendorID, Quantity, DateReceived,
        case when lag(VendorID) over(order by DateReceived) <> VendorID then 1 else 0 end as rn
    from Table1
), cte2 as (
    select
        VendorID, Quantity, sum(rn) over(order by DateReceived) as s
    from cte 
)
select
    VendorID, sum(Quantity)
from cte2
group by VendorID, s
order by s asc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5032a/17)</kbd>**

BTW, looks like your output is incorrect. Correct one would be:

```
+----------+----------+
| VendorID | Quantity |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        6 |
|        2 |        3 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        1 |        9 |
|        3 |        9 |
|        2 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```