# MySQL query grouped by contigious foreign key values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this:

```
+----+-------------------------+----------+----------+
| ID |      DateReceived       | Quantity | VendorID |
+----+-------------------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2010-08-09 06:53:44.783 |        2 |        1 |
|  2 | 2010-08-01 13:31:26.893 |        1 |        1 |
|  3 | 2010-07-26 07:52:29.403 |        2 |        1 |
|  4 | 2011-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
|  5 | 2011-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
|  6 | 2011-03-22 11:27:01.000 |        1 |        2 |
|  7 | 2011-03-18 09:04:58.000 |        1 |        1 |
|  8 | 2011-12-17 08:21:29.000 |        1 |        3 |
|  9 | 2012-08-10 10:55:20.000 |        9 |        3 |
| 10 | 2012-08-02 20:18:10.000 |        5 |        1 |
| 11 | 2012-07-12 20:44:36.000 |        3 |        1 |
| 12 | 2012-07-05 20:45:29.000 |        1 |        1 |
| 13 | 2013-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
| 14 | 2013-03-22 13:31:11.000 |        1 |        2 |
+----+-------------------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to sort the data by the `DateReceived` and sum the `Quantity`. BUT, I want to sum the `Quantity` grouped by the `VendorID` as long as they are adjacent (when sorted by `DateReceived`) like the example output below.

```
+----------+----------+
| VendorID | Quantity |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        5 |
|        2 |        3 |
|        1 |        1 |
|        3 |       10 |
|        1 |        9 |
|        2 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```

I think the answer has something to do with variables, but I can't think through how to do it.

What is a MySQL query to generate the desired output?

*note: I asked the [exact same thing here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19573892/107768) but for MS Sql, I now need this for MySQL.*

Comment: How did you get `|        1 |        9 |` row? Please explain.

Comment: @PM77-1 By summing the `Quantity` field for `VendorID` 1. (Rows ID 10-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
VendorID,
SUM(Quantity)
from (
select
t.*,
@grn := if(@prev != VendorID, @grn + 1, @grn) as grn,
@prev := VendorID
from
t
, (select @grn := 0, @prev := null) var_init
order by DateReceived
) sq
GROUP BY grn
```

But your expected output is wrong. You can see this by executing just this:

```
select
t.*,
@grn := if(@prev != VendorID, @grn + 1, @grn) as grn,
@prev := VendorID
from
t
, (select @grn := 0, @prev := null) var_init
order by DateReceived
```

Which results in:

```
| ID |                    DATERECEIVED | QUANTITY | VENDORID | GRN | @PREV := VENDORID |
|----|---------------------------------|----------|----------|-----|-------------------|
|  3 |     July, 26 2010 07:52:29+0000 |        2 |        1 |   0 |                 1 |
|  2 |   August, 01 2010 13:31:26+0000 |        1 |        1 |   0 |                 1 |
|  1 |   August, 09 2010 06:53:44+0000 |        2 |        1 |   0 |                 1 |
|  7 |    March, 18 2011 09:04:58+0000 |        1 |        1 |   0 |                 1 |
|  6 |    March, 22 2011 11:27:01+0000 |        1 |        2 |   1 |                 2 |
|  4 |    March, 22 2011 13:31:11+0000 |        1 |        2 |   1 |                 2 |
|  5 |    March, 22 2011 13:31:11+0000 |        1 |        2 |   1 |                 2 |
|  8 | December, 17 2011 08:21:29+0000 |        1 |        3 |   2 |                 3 |
| 12 |     July, 05 2012 20:45:29+0000 |        1 |        1 |   3 |                 1 |
| 11 |     July, 12 2012 20:44:36+0000 |        3 |        1 |   3 |                 1 |
| 10 |   August, 02 2012 20:18:10+0000 |        5 |        1 |   3 |                 1 |
|  9 |   August, 10 2012 10:55:20+0000 |        9 |        3 |   4 |                 3 |
| 13 |    March, 22 2013 13:31:11+0000 |        1 |        2 |   5 |                 2 |
| 14 |    March, 22 2013 13:31:11+0000 |        1 |        2 |   5 |                 2 |
```

Result of the whole query:

```
| VENDORID | SUM(QUANTITY) |
|----------|---------------|
|        1 |             6 |
|        2 |             3 |
|        3 |             1 |
|        1 |             9 |
|        3 |             9 |
|        2 |             2 |
```

- **<kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fe802/1/0)</kbd>**